# why does name injection while programming with dplyr behave differently in different iterations with the same data?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm not sure what is happening here but can anyone explain why this variable does not get correctly converted to a factor on the first iteration only?

```
# a tibble
datF <- tibble::tibble(
  short.week.label = c("3/29 to 4/1", "4/2 to 4/8", "1/1 to 1/2"),
  Species = "LACI"
)


# function to convert weekLabel column to factor
tempFunc <- function(datF, weekLabel) {
  datF %>%
    dplyr::mutate({{weekLabel}} :=
                    factor(datF[[weekLabel]],
                           levels = unique(datF[[weekLabel]]),
                           ordered = TRUE))
}


# Question is why does the first iteration make a new column with
# the name of the variable rather than the value of the variable
# which is what I intend?

# a variable
weekLabel <- "short.week.label"

purrr::map(
  list(datF, datF, datF),
  tempFunc,
  weekLabel = weekLabel
)
```

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77761757/mutate-filter-column-which-has-same-name-as-another-dataframe)?   In the first iteration, there's no matching symbol in the data frame, only in the "environment".  In subsequent iterations, there is a matching symbol in the data frame?  Just guessing...

Comment: I think this is related to [stringr::str_glue() doesn't work with purrr::map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77709059/stringrstr-glue-doesnt-work-with-purrrmap/77709150#77709150). Unexpected things seem to happen when `purrr::map()` evaluates symbols that you would expect to be in function scope - they sometimes don't seem to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to explain the exact behavior but it seems related to lazy evaluation. If you add `force(weekLabel)` to the start of your `tempFunc` that would "fix" it. The problem is that `{{}}` uses non-standard evaluation which you would use for symbols so it keeps the value as a promise, but then you use `datF[[weekLabel]]` which uses standard evaluation so the value is in a non-promise state for future iterations. Another way to see this is with

```
# ALSO TRIGGERS ERROR - DO NOT USE
tempFunc <- function(datF, weekLabel) {
  datF %>%
    dplyr::mutate({{weekLabel}} :=
                    factor(short.week.label,
                           levels = unique(short.week.label),
                           ordered = TRUE))
}
```

this code uses `{{}}` but does not ever resolve the promise so you get the same value on every iteration. Simplifying the example to not use `dplyr`, see

```
# ANOTHER WAY TO REPLICATE THE ERROR
tempFunc <- function(val, weekLabel) {
  c(rlang::englue("{{weekLabel}} + {val}"), weekLabel)
}

test <- "apple"
purrr::map(1:3, tempFunc, weekLabel = test)
# [[1]]
# [1] "test + 1" "apple"   
# [[2]]
# [1] "\"apple\" + 2" "apple"        
# [[3]]
# [1] "\"apple\" + 3" "apple"
```

So once the promise is collapsed, it stays collapsed. So the takeaway would be not to use `{{}}` with things should not be lazily evaluated.

The better way to address this is to fix your `dplyr` syntax. The recommended way to do this would be.

```
tempFunc <- function(datF, weekLabel) {
  datF %>%
    dplyr::mutate("{weekLabel}" :=
                    factor(.data[[weekLabel]],
                           levels = unique(.data[[weekLabel]]),
                           ordered = TRUE))
}
```

If you are passing in a string as `weekLabel`, you want to use the `.data` pronoun to extract the correct value rather than re-using the data.frame variable name in the `mutate`. Plus you should use the proper glue-style syntax for creating new variable column names. See [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

We could use the bang-bang operator:

Remove the curly curly next to mutate.

`{{weekLabel}}` will use `weekLabel` as a literal column name. Therefore  you get an extra column in the first iteration.
To achieve the desired behaviour we can use the bang-bang operator that will force to evaluate `weekLabel` correctly.

```
tempFunc <- function(datF, weekLabel) {
  datF %>%
    dplyr::mutate(!!weekLabel :=
                    factor(datF[[weekLabel]],
                           levels = unique(datF[[weekLabel]]),
                           ordered = TRUE))
}
```

Comment: While technically you can use `!!`, this isn't the way recommended by the dplyr authors. It's not used in the official programing guide: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: @MrFlick I'm not very well-read yet and am only starting to slowly understand things. I am primarily still focused on finding solutions and am happy that it works. But thank you very much for your feedback, as always, it's enriching! And may I draw your attention to [this maybe related question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77761757/mutate-filter-column-which-has-same-name-as-another-dataframe/77762919#77762919)